# Get class of annotated field as default value for custom annotation

Tags: java, annotations

I have started to write some annotations to make it easier for me to define model classes for information in some of my bukkit plugins.

Simplified speaking, I currently have two annotations, called `@Model` and `@Field`. One is to mark a class as model for some information, and the other one is to mark a field as being transposed into a database column:

Field:

```java
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface Field {
    public Class type();
}
```

Model:

```java
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface Model {
}
```

I created a class for testing purposes that uses these Annotations:

```java
import bukkitutils.sql.Field;
import bukkitutils.sql.Model;

@Model
public class ExampleModelClass {

    @Field(type = String.class)
    private String exampleStringField = "default value";
}
```

This seems to work fine, I can pass a class as annotation property. My Question is:

How can I make this property take the default value of `String.class`, so I wouldn't have to specify it, If I want the property to just be the same class as the field.?

I understand that I can specify the default value with e.g. `public String exampleString() default "exampledefault"`, but how can I do so to get the class of the field in it?

Comment: You would need to write an annotation processor, I think.

Comment: Yes that's clear... But how can it help me to make the type property of my annotation optional?

Comment: You write an annotation processor that adds in the correct `.class` for you.

Comment: So the solution would be to just set the default of `type` to something very specific, maybe like an extra created `NeverUsedAnywhere.class`, and then check first if the value has been changed, and if not get the `class` from the annotated field in the processor?

Comment: Or you could even make a new annotation like `@AutoField`, as opposed to just `@Field`. The annotation processor will just process `@AutoField`.

Comment: And @Field will require the specification of the `type`, while @AutoField would always determine the class in the processor?

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought.